# Questions about ASP.NET Core MVC Null Exception error handling

Tags: exception, null, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Entity Framework Core. Everything is working fine, I can create, update and delete records in the database EXCEPT displaying the item in a view.

I have validation checks at view so no records had NULL values.

display.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAppReview.Models.ItemReview>

@if (Model.Count() > 0)
   ... some code ...

@if (Model != null)
   ... some code ...
```

The conditions keep throwing this error:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
> System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)

Question: what is the root cause of this error?

1. Is it because the way I check for null is wrong?
2. Is it the connection string? But I can create, update and delete items to database. Hence it should be fine ...
3. What is the proper way to "force" populate 'Model' with the database data?

Please help!

Comment: That is because your model is null,so the `Model.Count() > 0` statement will always throw such exception.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your model is null,so the `Model.Count() > 0` statement will always throw such exception.So you need judge the Model is null or not firstly.

Change like below:

```
@if (Model!=null && Model.Count() > 0)
{
    //do your stuff...
}

@if (Model != null)
{    
    //do your stuff...      
}
```

Not sure what is your real scenario,but the two statements are similar,it seems the difference is that `count` equals 0 or not.The above statements will display two code sample if `Model.Count==0`.If you want to distinguish the two statement,I think you need change like below:

```
@if (Model!=null && Model.Count() > 0)
{
    //do your stuff...
}

@if (Model != null && Model.Count()== 0)
{    
    //do your stuff...      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @if ( Model != null && Model.Count() > 0 ){
           //do your stuff...
 }
 else{
          //do your stuff...
 }
```

This arrangement works for me.

Taking Null check at the beginning.

But in this case, probably you are not calling the model in the controller

Check with this example, this is the right way:-

```
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<YourModel> objList = _db.yourModel;
        return View(objList);
        //   return View();
    }
```